# Ajax.ActionLink creating unwanted link

Tags: html, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In my second navigation bar, I have many Ajax links which I created like this:

`<li><a href=@Ajax.ActionLink("AVPartial", "SecurityProfiles",new AjaxOptions{UpdateTargetId = "SPContainer"})><span>Antivirus</span></a></li>`

The problem is when clicking these links I get the following error:

`A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (<).`

And the link i am redirected to is :
http://localhost:8680/SecurityProfiles/%3Ca
as the %3Ca is a inferior character (<).

Can anyway explain why is this happening and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why include `<a>` tag?

`ActionLink` itself creates the tag

```
<li>
  @Ajax.ActionLink("Antivirus", "SecurityProfiles",new AjaxOptions{UpdateTargetId = "SPContainer"})>
</li>
```

EDIT:

First argument to `@Ajax.ActionLink()` is Text to display